# Is there a theory for the largest possible Black Hole?

Tags: black-holes

I am aware that there is a minimum size of a Black Hole where it functions according to our theories of the universe, that being defined by the Plank Mass, if I understand correctly.

But, my question is, given an essentially infinite amount of mass to pull from (thus ignoring the limitations that come from just the amount of matter. As with said limitation it is 23547596586.294921875 Light Years due to mass limits), is there a size of a Black Hole where scientists believe that it would stop functioning in the way in which we understand it?

Comment: That's a lot of significant figures for a light year count... or anything.

Comment: [These](https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.2813) [papers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.08502) argue for upper bounds in the billions of Solar masses.

Comment: I am aware it is more significant figures then necessary, I just didn't feel like cutting it down after calculating it, 23547596586.29 should be enough looking at it. and thanks for the paper.

Comment: Papers, plural; the links are just adjacent. Never quote spurious significant figures; calculate the uncertainty [with this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty) to know the correct number of SF.